How can I get the value of a select element on mouseover?
I have searched for this and so far have not found a solution, unless it's to use a plugin or change the select dropdown to a list and style it.
Is it possible to capture the value of a select option as you hover over it?
I have the following dropdown:
<select id="testSelect">
    <option value="0">Disable</option>
    <option value="1">Enable</option>
    <option value="2">Hidden</option>
    <option value="4">Failover</option>
</select>

I've tried using the following but nothing is shown in the console log.
$('#testSelect :option').mouseover(function(e) {
    console.log ( $(this).val() )
})

Is this possible, and if it is how do I get the value of the option as I hover over it? I need this to be supported in Edge, Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

"or change the select dropdown to a list and style it" - That's probably the way to go.  The native <select> is very host-dependent and somewhat limited.

That's how plugins like Select2 work.

That's why plugins like [tag:select2] are available.

Is it possible to capture the value of a select option as you hover over it - no.   The select dropdown is not part of the DOM (it's part of the browser) and thus does not provide DOM events etc.

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

It's not possible with native HTML and CSS.
You would have to create your own dropdown element (see below) to add a MouseEnter event:
$('.custom-select').on('mouseenter', '.option', function() {
  console.log('Moused-over:', $(this).data('value'));
});

Here is a jQuery plugin that locates select elements by a jQuery selector and convert them to a custom select dropdown element.
It's fairly simple. The placeholder ad classes are also configurable.


(function($) {
  const defaultSettings = {
    placeholder: 'Select an option',
    containerClass: 'custom-select',
    selectedClass: 'selected-option',
    dropdownClass: 'options-container',
    optionClass: 'option'
  };

  $.fn.customSelect = function(options) {
    const opts = $.extend({}, defaultSettings, options);

    this.hide().each(function() {
      const $originalSelect = $(this);
      const $customDropdown = $(`
        <div class="${opts.containerClass}">
          <div class="${opts.selectedClass}">${opts.placeholder}</div>
          <div class="${opts.dropdownClass}">
            ${$originalSelect.find('option').map((_, option) => `
              <div class="${opts.optionClass}" data-value="${option.value}">${option.text}</div>
            `).get().join('')}
          </div>
        </div>
      `);

      const $selected = $customDropdown.find(`.${opts.selectedClass}`);
      const $optionsContainer = $customDropdown.find(`.${opts.dropdownClass}`);
      
      $originalSelect.after($customDropdown);

      $selected.on('click', () => $optionsContainer.toggle());

      $optionsContainer.on('click', `.${opts.optionClass}`, function() {
        const $clickedOption = $(this);
        $selected.text($clickedOption.text()).data('value', $clickedOption.data('value'));
        $originalSelect.val($clickedOption.data('value')).trigger('change');
        $optionsContainer.hide();
      });

      $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).closest($customDropdown).length) {
          $optionsContainer.hide();
        }
      });
    });

    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#testSelect').customSelect().on('change', function() {
    console.log('Changed value', $(this).val());
  });

  $('.custom-select').on('mouseenter', '.option', function() {
    console.log('Moused-over:', $(this).data('value'));
  });
});
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  width: 12rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selected-option {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
.options-container {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
}
.option {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
.option:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="testSelect">
  <option value="0">Disable</option>
  <option value="1">Enable</option>
  <option value="2">Hidden</option>
  <option value="3">Failover</option>
</select>




Thanks, This will help however I'm not sure I'll be able to apply it, as there are restrictions  to what I can change.
